# gazebo crashes on startup

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Running the command

```
gazebo
```

opens two blank windows, then closes them, then opens a window with a nice toolbar and stuff that looks like it's doing what it's supposed to do. A fraction of a second later, the program closes. It doesn't seem to have any sort of error message. It just has

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.7.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.7.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.xxx.yyy

Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.xxx.yyy
```

I also tried running gzserver and gzclient on separate terminals. gzserver seems to work fine.

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.7.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://127.0.0.1:11345
Msg Publicized address: 10.0.xxx.yyy
```

However, gzclient does not.

```
gzclient: error while loading shared libraries: liburdfdom_model.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Edit:

Sourcing did nothing.

gazebo /usr/empty_world.sdf got me

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.7.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master.Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.7.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Error [SystemPaths.cc:370] File or path does not exist["/usr/empty_world.sdf"]
Error [Server.cc:259] Could not open file[/usr/empty_world.sdf]

Error [ConnectionManager.cc:88] Connection Manager is not running
```

Attempting to install ROS with the instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Ubuntu) failed on step 1.5:

```
sudo rosdep init
```

which gave me:

```
sudo: rosdep: command not found
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2499/gazebo-crashes-on-startup/) by [DanielLC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/321/daniellc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-23**:
I think this can fix your problem. Source: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros_enabled_model_plugin

source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash

source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh

export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=~/local/lib/gazebo_plugins:${GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH}

export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=~/gazebo_ros_plugin/models:${GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH}

gazebo ~/gazebo_ros_plugin/<your_world_file>.world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. How did you install gazebo?
2. Can you run just `gzserver`?
3. If you can run `gzserver`, try running `gzstats` in another terminal while `gzserver` is running.
4. `gazebo /usr/empty_world.sdf` is a bad command, as the resulting error messages indicate. The file `/usr/empty_world.sdf` does not exist.
5. Can you provide a backtrace?

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0